# Bind a list in the `WHERE` clause?

Tags: soql, query

Is it possible to construct a SOQL query with a list literal in the `WHERE` clause?

I have this query:

```
bookings = [SELECT Asset__c A, Asset__r.Name An FROM Booking__c WHERE 
                ((Date_begin__c IN (2017-08-10, 2017-08-16, 2017-08-25,2017-08-29, 2017-08-21, 2017-08-23)) OR 
                 (Date_end__c IN (2017-08-16, 2017-08-17, 2017-08-29, 2017-08-22, 2017-08-26, 2017-08-27))) GROUP BY Asset__c, Asset__r.Name];
```

I don't want use the dates in hard code like your see in this example.

I have the dates on other list

```
DateBeginList = new List<Date>(); 
/* examble  */
DateBeginList = (2017-08-21 00:00:00, 2017-08-29 00:00:00, 2017-08-23 00:00:00, 2017-08-10 00:00:00)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please refrain from using all caps.

Comment: When an answer [addresses your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this through variable binding:

```
Date[] startDates = new Date[] { Date.newInstance(2017, 8, 21), Date.newInstance(... };
bookings = [SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Date_Begin__c IN :startDates ...];
```

You can read more about it in [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm).

Comment: And if you are like me and are coming from the SQL world note that this won't work: `WHERE Date_Begin__c IN (:startDates)` with parens...

Comment: @Shane This works: `String hello = 'hello', world = 'world'; Account[] records = [select id from account where name in (:hello, :world)];` Parentheses can be used for single values, but not for collections. You can use either or, but not both at the same time.